# Remove method of the List is not working

Tags: grails

I am creating a session variable in one controller-:

```
List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>()
emp = Employee.findAllByLevel(proj_lev.level_no)
session.employee_list = emp

render(view: "add_members", model: [proj_lev:proj_lev , proj_lev_right:proj_lev_right , employee:session.employee_list])
```

In another controller I am accessing the session variable and using the remove method of the List but the list is not changing-:

```
render "${session.employee_list}"
def emp_added = Employee.get(params.int('employee_id'))
session.employee_list.remove(emp_added)
render "${session.employee_list}"
```

The view in the GSP is-:

```
 [tearp.Employee : 2, tearp.Employee : 5, tearp.Employee : 8, tearp.Employee : 9, tearp.Employee : 10][tearp.Employee : 2, tearp.Employee : 5, tearp.Employee : 8, tearp.Employee : 9, tearp.Employee : 10]
```

Comment: why are you calling render two times?

Comment: I want to check the status of the list before and after removing the object from the list, so I am calling 2 times.

Comment: You are using list in session . you have to replace list in session after removing element from list .

Comment: List<Employee> new_list = new ArrayList<Employee>()
  new_list=session.employee_list.remove(emp_added)
session.employee_list= new_list
but still not working. the erro shown is-:
Cannot cast object 'false' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'java.util.List' in the line-:
new_list=session.employee_list.remove(emp_added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a list of employee to be removed , and then remove this list from "added employees"  and  add this list to "all employees"

Answer (score 0):

*Have you override **equals** method on `Employee` domain object?* I think that is the problem.

When you say this ( with out overriding the equals method):

```
session.employee_list.remove(emp_added)
```

It will first search the object in the list by its hashcode and every time you fetch an object from db using `Employee.get(..)` hibernate creates new object even for the same record, so every new object has new hashcode and `list.remove()` method wont work as far as the object is not found on the list.

#### Possible Solution:

add this method on your `Employee` domain class:

```
@Overrid
boolean equals(Employee employee){

return this.id == employee?.id

}
```